# What differences are between testable theories and falsifiable hypotheses?

Tags: test

*Psychology: the Core Concepts* says

> Psychology  differs  from  the  pseudosciences  in  that  it  employs
> the scientific method to test its ideas empirically.  The scientific
> method  relies on testable theories and falsifi- able hypotheses.

What differences are between testable theories and falsifiable hypotheses?

What differences are between theories and hypotheses? Are they the same?

Answer (score 1):

https://www.merriam-webster.com/grammar/difference-between-hypothesis-and-theory-usage

https://www.dictionary.com/e/theory-vs-hypothesis/

https://undsci.berkeley.edu/understanding-science-101/how-science-works/science-at-multiple-levels/

Typically, "theory" describes explanation of how the world works in some way. Hypotheses are more specific. A theory would suggest hypotheses that can be tested: the theory makes predictions about whether certain hypotheses are true or not.

A theory could be that the left hemisphere of the brain controls muscles on the right side of the body. A resulting hypothesis might be that people who have weakness on the right side of the body after suffering a stroke have damage on the left side of their brain. If this hypothesis is correct, it supports the theory; if it's incorrect, it suggests the theory is wrong or incomplete. Other hypotheses might be that electrically stimulating right motor cortex will cause twitches or movements on the left side of the body, or that axonal pathways can be traced using retrograde labels from muscles to motoneurons and so on but eventually will cross to the opposite side.